# Solve $A^5=I$ (where $I$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matix) subject to the conditions $\det(A) \neq 0$ and $A^n \neq I$ for $n \lt 5.$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Can anyone solve the matrix equation $A^5=I$ where $I$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix and $A$ is such that $\det(A)$ is non-zero and $A^n \neq I$ for $n \lt 5.$

I have tried to solve it but I do not know how to solve matrix equations.I actually want to find an infinite group in GL(2,R) such that infinitely many elements of that group has an order of 5.

Comment: Note that the condition on the determinant of $A$ is unnecessary, as $I=A^5=AA^4=A^4A$ implies $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Yes,that's right.Thanks

Comment: I have edited the question,now it is fit for being answered,please remove [on hold].

Comment: I think K. Sadri answered your question – you just have to think a little bit about Sadri's answer, which you should be willing to do.

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers that have been posted, Kishalay?

Comment: Are you still here, Kishalay?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\xi=\exp(\frac{2i\pi}{5})$ (or any fifth root of unity other than $1$). Then the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}\xi&0\\0&\xi\end{pmatrix}$ should suffice.

Comment: Is there no other matrix satisfying the condition.THIS IS NOT A COMPLETE SET OF SOLNS

Comment: @KishalaySarkar  For this we need complete information on the coefficients. Is $A\in M_2(\Bbb Z)$, or has $A$ rational or real or complex coefficients?

Comment: A is a matrix in GL(2,R).

Answer (score 1):

OP indicates that what's wanted is a matrix $A$ with real entries. That means its characteristic polynomial $p(x)$ must be a factor of $(x^5-1)/(x-1)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ with real coefficients. Letting $z$ stand for $e^{2\pi i/5}$, the zeros of $p(x)$ (which are the eigenvalues of $A$) must be $z$ and $z^{-1}$, or $z^2$ and $z^{-2}$.

Taking the first case, $p(x)=x^2-(z+z^{-1})x+zz^{-1}=x^2-2\cos(2\pi/5)x+1$. One matrix that works is the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) to this polynomial, $$A_1=\pmatrix{0&-1\cr1&2\cos(2\pi/5)\cr}$$ which evidently has trace $2\cos(2\pi/5)$ and determinant $1$, as required. Any matrix similar to $A_1$ will also fill the bill, so $B=C^{-1}A_1C$ is an answer for any invertible real $2\times2$ matrix $C$.

Equivalently, the matrix that rotates everything in ${\bf R}^2$ by $2\pi/5$ counterclockwise, $$A_1'=\pmatrix{c&-s\cr s&c\cr}$$ where I've written $c$ and $s$ for $\cos(2\pi/5)$ and $\sin(2\pi/5)$, respectively, can be used, so we get $D^{-1}A_1'D$ as describing exactly the same set of matrices as above.

Now we come back to the other characteristic polynomial, $p(x)=(x-z^2)(x-z^{-2})=x^2-2\cos(4\pi/5)x+1$. This can be treated exactly as above, giving rise to a second infinite family of solutions. These two infinite families give all the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The firdt answer is true. But there is more. The most general is
$$A=S\begin{pmatrix}
\xi^a & 0\\
0 & \xi^b
\end{pmatrix} S^{-1}$$
For any S, and $(a, b)\in\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}$

Comment: How did you find it?

Comment: I think because conjugation preserves order.

Comment: Is the solution set infinite or finite.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A^5=I$, the matrix $A$ satisfies the polynomial $x^5-1$. In particular, the minimal polynomial must divide $x^5-1=(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1) = (x-1)(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^2)(x-\zeta^3)(x-\zeta^4)$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive fifth root of unity. For example, we can take $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/5}$.

Since $A\neq I$, the minimal polynomial is not $x-1$. But it can be any of:

1. $x-\zeta^i$, $i=1,\ldots 4$.
2. $(x-\zeta^i)(x-\zeta^j)$, with $0\leq i\lt j\leq 4$.

Since the minimal polynomial is of degree at most $2$, then those are the only possibilities. In none of those cases will we have $A^k=I$ for $1\leq k\leq 4$.

In all cases we have a diagonalizable matrix whose eigenvalues are the roots of the minimal polynmomial. That means that the matrix $A$ is **similar** to a matrix of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\zeta^i & 0\\
0 & \zeta^j
\end{array}\right)$$
where $0\leq i\leq j\leq 4$, **except* the case $i=j=0$ (which gives the identity).

When $i=j$, the only matrix similar to the given one is the given one; when $i\lt j$, you may get other matrices. For instance,
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{2}(1+\zeta) & \frac{1}{2}(1-\zeta)\\
\frac{1}{2}(1-\zeta) & \frac{1}{2})1+\zeta)
\end{array}\right)$$
is a solution, since it is similar to the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $1$ and $\zeta$.